# Unit testing of Firebase Cloud Functions which are connected to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have HTTP Cloud Functions written in JS which are using  promise pools to connect to MySQL database. They work but I want to create some unit tests for them.

I am wondering what should the process look like. I read the documentation of Firebase on unit tests but I just can't figure out how to do it with 'external' database. All of the examples I found are with Firestore or with Real Time database of Firebase.

Here is a snippet of one of my cloud functions:

```
// mysql.js

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
...
});
const promisePool = pool.promise();


exports.getRoots = functions.region('europe-west3').runWith({timeoutSeconds: 180}).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    var sqlStr1 = "CALL get_roots(@temp);";
    var sqlStr2 = "SELECT @temp;";
    try{
        console.log('Query starting...');
        const [rows1, fields1] = await promisePool.query(sqlStr1);
        const [rows2, fields2] = await promisePool.query(sqlStr2);
        result = rows2[0]['@temp'];
        console.log('Result received!');
        console.log("Result:" + result);
        return {data: JSON.parse(result)};
    } catch (error){
        console.log("ERROR!");
        console.log(error);
    }
    return null;
});
```

```
// index.js
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); admin.initializeApp(); exports.mysql = require('./mysql');
```

I have a folder called 'test' in the 'function' folder and inside is the index.test.js file according to the documentation. Currently I have this in the file:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions-test");

const test = require('firebase-functions-test')({
    databaseURL: 'https://projectX.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: 'projectX.appspot.com',
    projectId: 'projectX',
  }, 'test\projectXKey.json');

const mysql = require('../mysql.js');
const wrappedGetRoots = test.wrap(mysql.getRoots);
```

... but I am not sure how to proceed.

```
// index.test.js
  
describe("Testing getRoots", () => {
    const wrappedGetRoots = test.wrap(mysql.getRoots);
    it('Getting roots does work', async(done) =>{
        const data = {};
        await wrappedGetRoots(data).then(async (response: any)=>{
            expect(response.status).toBe('OK')
            done()
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            fail('Failed: ' + error)
        })
    })
  })
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work"? Please provide exact error message or describe unexpected behaviour in detail!

Comment: @Shadow
"SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on the line 
- await wrappedGetRoots(data).then(async (response: any)=>{

My JS skills are on beginner-intermediate level tho, I am not sure where is the mistake in syntax. The version of my NodeJS is v18.16.0

Comment: Then your question has nothing to do with mysql, firebase, cloud function, nor unit testing....

Comment: @Shadow
After removing the 'any' part after the response, the test seems to run but the error is now with promisePool. 
"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306""
"     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\X\functions\test\index.test.js)"